# SSRS Report renders differently in Browser to Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, ssrs-2017

SSRS 2017 Report Builder correctly renders report with drilldown buttons and field data. When rendered in the browser both the drilldown and field data are not visible.

Edge, Chrome and IE all hide the field with the drilldown button on it.
The fault appears to lie with css in .MSRS-RVC `.tdResizable overflow:hidden`, as if this is unticked (both in Chrome & IE Devtools) the fields are correctly shown, and work normally.

Edge screen grab showing missing fields:

[image]

Report Builder Screen shot showing how it should look with drop down buttons

[image]

SSRS Version

[image]

I have tried editing 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer\Styles\htmlviewer.css' by adding

```
.MSRS-RVC .tdResizable {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

to the bottom, however this has made no difference (I have restarted SSRS, but have not rebooted the server). Not sure I'm looking in the right place really...

Comment: You might want to double check this, however, I believe some of those interactive options are only accessible in Compatibility Mode when using IE>=11.

Comment: Thanks - I have tried in Compatibility mode, but that made no difference. I also get the same results in Chrome & Edge, so it's not specific to IE.

Comment: The functionality works when you export to PDF and Excel, correct?

Comment: Please provide screenshot of the RDL file "Row Groups" and the "Row Group Properties> GENERAL, VISIBILITY".  It is possible that one of the settings is not properly configured.  You might try tweaking the settings... the Visibility should be set as [SHOW] & [DISPLAY CAN BE TOGGLED BY : <MyDataField>].  Just play around with the ROW GROUPS (all of them), and see if you can get the group visibility correctly functioning.

Comment: When Exporting to Excel it works perfectly, regardless of how it displays

Comment: This isn't particularly surprising, when using the 'preview' in Visual Studio, it often helps to delete the '.data' files and the '.rptproj.ruser' file in the same directory as the '.rdl' file.  NOTE:  do not delete the '.rptproj' file.

Answer (score 2):

I have modified the 'Can Grow' attribute to True on the field that was not visible, and this has resolved the issue. This should not really have made any difference, as the data is a fixed length and the report was easily wide enough to accommodate it (I even made it much wider to it to see if that was an issue), but that made no difference.

I can only presume that, in the background, the addition of the + button exceeded the row height set. This was working just fine with previous versions of SSRS, so the 2017 version must have a larger image for that button for some reason!

Hope this helps someone else in future!